# Program not following while statement

Tags: c, loops

Using visual studio 2015 "C"
I'm asking the user to enter a number between 3-40, if the user doesn't enter a proper value, it will enter the while statement, and constantly loop and ask again until they enter a valid value, however no matter what, it always enters the while loop and will only loop once.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int counter;
int marks;



printf("---=== IPC mark Analyser ===---\n");

printf("Please enter the number of marks(between 3 and 40): ");
scanf("%d", &counter);

while (counter >40 || counter <3);
{
    printf("Invalid number, enter a number between 3 and 40 inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &counter);
} 


    printf("");

}
```

Comment: my bad didn't know I added it

Comment: Learn how to use the built-in debugger in Visual Studio. It is very good. With it you can step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Ok, but do you notice any problems with the code itself

Answer (score 3):

```
while (counter >40 || counter <3);
```

You have to remove the semicolon.

```
while (counter >40 || counter <3)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. May I ask why the semi colon caused the problem?

Comment: The grammar allows loop body to be a single expression (without `{}`), even an empty expression. And you can use `{}` to add another scope, for example to control lifetime of variables, and that's why the second `scanf` always executed, no matter what you entered the first time.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is trailing ";" on your while line :)

Answer (score 0):

Also it is best coding practice to set variables to zero to remove possible junk data that could be located in memory

Comment: It's definitely a best practice to remove unused variables.  When the variable is set by an input statement, there's no particular merit in zeroing it, though the code should check that the input is successful before using the value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the semicolon after while loop and because of this your program seems it as a statement.

The correct code is Given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int counter;
int marks;



printf("---=== IPC mark Analyser ===---\n");

printf("Please enter the number of marks(between 3 and 40): ");
scanf("%d", &counter);

while (counter >40 || counter <3)
{
    printf("Invalid number, enter a number between 3 and 40 inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &counter);
}


    printf("");

}
```